# Xcode 8 - Entitlements file messed up

Tags: xcode, push

I wanted to use Push Notifications in my app. So I set everything up in Apple's member center and made new provisioning profiles and so on. 
The provisioning profile contains push support as well as my app id. 
The problem is, each time I toggle the Push notifications button in the "Capabilities" tab, Xcode creates two new empty (!) entitlement files. 
What is going on there? The debugger says as I try to register for push notifications: "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application". Can someone help?

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Comment: Did you added push notifications capability to provisioning profile at developer.apple.com ?

Comment: yeah i did. Fixed it. See my reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of fixed: Added two new .entitlement files manually and added them in the code signing box in the info.plist as "TargetName"_dev.entitlement for debug and "TargetName"_prod.entitlement for release. Thus the capability tab works and adds entitlements to these two files correctly. 
Smh, there has to be a cleaner way...

Comment: Can you post the content of the original entitlement file since there is might be some errors on it.

Comment: Hah, I would if it existed... That's been the problem I guess.